# Uitextfield "losing" text value between view flips

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm a days-old iphone programmer - I'm writing a simple program based on the utility xcode template. I have a uitextfield that writes its value into a singleton object on edit. I also have implemented key observation on changes to this value. This works fine. When I flip the view to the second "flipside view" and back again the value is reset.

I'm trying to get the textfield to retain its value between flips.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you creating this UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

Re-set your value in viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear. Maybe you are getting memory warning and view controller releases it's view?

Comment: The UITextField is probably not retained, or reset as commented above. Post your code.